# Preserve then() catch() format when using Prettier JS

Tags: javascript, formatting, format, visual-studio-code, prettier

I just started using the [PrettierJS](https://github.com/prettier/prettier) Plugin for VSCode and I am looking for a way to preserve my code format of my service calls (and subsequent Promises).

I know you can add the `//prettier-ignore` comments just before the code block to preserve the code pattern, but since i do this all over my app, i do not want to add that comment-line everywhere.

Right now, my code block looks like this:

```
       return this.thingService.addThing(newThing)
            .then(wonFunction)
            .catch(lostFunction);
```

But when i do the Prettier format command i get this:

```
    return this.accessData.addRight(newRight).then(wonAddAccessRight).catch(lostAddAccessRight);
```

I want a way to preserve my code blocks from changing without using the `//prettier-ignore` comments.

Answer (score 7):

Prettier now automatically breaks a chain of 3 or more functions in separate lines (current version as I'm writing is 1.9.1), so the formatting is a bit different from what OP requested:

```js
return this.accessData
  .addRight(newRight)
  .then(wonAddAccessRight)
  .catch(lostAddAccessRight);
```

But if you wanted to force it to break if you have only 2 functions, there's a hack that is to add a comment and Prettier will automatically break it:

```js
return promise // force break
  .then(didResolve)
  .catch(didReject);
```

Comment: fugly, why isn't it an official fix instead of the comment hack I wonder